# screen is broke at the bottom

Tags: sync

[image]

I had just bought  zte  Android phone. An I was short on cash so I didnt get the insurance an went to leave an dropped it. I hadn't even  activate activate it yet. Is there anyway I can use for keyboard just till I get passed set up.

Comment: Did you try tilting the phone so that the screen can rotate? auto rotate feature is enabled by default - I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about that. Could you please refine your mobile model? If it supports OTG, you can use OTG Cable(would cost you around $1) to connect an external mouse or a keyboard to mobile to complete the setup.